# The website was working fine but from last 10 days when we try to access any page its show 502

Tags: asp.net, iis

The website was working fine but from last 10 days when we try to access any page its  show 502 and when this error occurs the whole website stop working. After few min its again start working but works 1 or 2 min again 502 occurred. Even we not able to access login page which contains only two text box and a button when 502 occurred.

Answer (score 0):

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/502error.htm

The Bad Gateway error can be customized by each website. While this isn't very common, different web servers do describe this error differently. Here are some common ways you might see it:

Comment: Thanks hemant !! I try different ideas but still not able to resolve. Actually when 502 occurred all the logged user get 502 and server memory utilization increases drastically   . Is it IIS issue or network issue or related with application .

Comment: this  can help you with the  issue   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2005/09/21/howto-diagnose-iis6-failing-to-accept-connections-due-to-connections-refused.aspx